# Как сделать редирект так, чтобы он работал в Google Chrome?

Tags: редирект, php, javascript

Версия Google Chrome - 25.0.1364.172 m

Принцип работы такой:

1. Пользователь посещает страницу (скрипт №1)
2. Он выполняется
3. После этого отправляется заголовок (редирект на скрипт №2)
4. Скрипт №2 принимает эстафету
5. Выполняется
6. Возвращает эстафету скрипту №1 и скрипт №1 показывает результат

Проблема в защите браузера. Если я делаю заголовками, возникает ошибка 310. А если пытаюсь закончить работу скрипта №2 выводом в браузер редиректирующего javascript кода или мета-тега refresh, браузер просто зацикливается обновляя страницу (скрипт №2), даже если указано, что переадресовывать нужно на другой поддомен, не говоря уже о другой директории этого же домена. Переадресовывает только если домен назначения совсем другой.

У кого-нибудь есть мысли в чём может быть причина такого странного поведения браузера? И что делать? Нужно чтобы такой принцип эстафеты работал во всех браузерах.

UPD

Зачем тут код, если вопрос не про код? Ну да ладно. Код примерно такой:

script1.php

```
<?

header ("Location: script2.php"); exit();

?>
```

script2.php

```
<?

header ("Location: script1.php"); exit();

?>
```

Только весь смысл в том, что в первом скрипте сначала идёт условие, и если оно не выполняется, то тогда идёт обращение ко второму скрипту, который заносит в базу данных необходимые данные и когда второй скрипт доделывает свои дела, должен повторяться запрос к первому скрипту, в котором условие уже будет выполняться (благодаря проделанной работе второго скрипта) и соответственно первый скрипт уже не будет обращаться ко второму скрипту и будет производить совсем другие действия не связанные с редиректами.

UPD2

script1.php

```
<?
Если переменная $_SESSION['category'] == '2' то выводим слово "БДСМ", а если нет, то делаем редирект на второй скрипт
header ("Location: script2.php"); exit();

?>
```

script2.php

```
<?

$_SESSION['category'] = '2';
header ("Location: script1.php"); exit();

?>
```

Простой пример с сессионной переменной. Ну уж теперь-то все поняли логику? :))) Я понимаю, что можно всё в одном скрипте сделать и это будет прекрасно работать, но мне интересно, можно ли как-нибудь распределить обязанности на разные скрипты, чтобы они работали по принципу передачи эстефетной палочки, ну или как бы играли в "сифу" до определённого момента. :) Я не знаю уже как мальчикам объяснить то, чего я хочу добиться от Google ChromА. :)))))

UPD 3

То что я привела в пример - я не тестировала и это работает да, но почему-то, когда работают два настоящих больших скрипта, происходят глюки или ошибки описанные выше и причём только в Google Chrome, хотя в скриптах нет ничего особенного и в общем смысле они логически сложены так же как мой пример с сессиями, только скрипты работают с базой данных и не передают друг другу ничего, а просто первый говорит второму - "у меня нет данных, поработай-ка и ты". Код прикладывать не буду, потому что мне совесть не позволит просить кого-нибудь в нём разобраться. :)))

Простите за "охоту за приведениями". :) Всем большое спасибо, особенно [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) и моему другу [[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus). :)))

Comment: Пока что я не придумала ничего лучше, чем передавать эстафету из первого скрипта второму cURL-ом и затем делать редирект на скрипт №1. То есть, во время выполнения скрипта №1 он как бы вызывает скрипт №2 и затем начинается сначала, но после работы второго скрипта он уже показывает результат, как и нужно, а не передаёт эстафету.

Ужас, я уже даже не надеюсь, что кто-то понимает, что я имею ввиду. :)))

Comment: Ой. Нет. Всё равно ошибка 310. Браузеру как бы пофиг, что условия поменялись и для него переадресация со страницы на саму себя - это как бы зло. :(

Comment: Наверное, таки придётся всю логику запихивать в один скрипт. :(

Comment: >возникает ошибка 310

Какая-какая "ошибка"?

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, а можно пример кода, чтобы воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: > Ужас, я уже даже не надеюсь, что кто-то понимает, что я имею ввиду. :)))

А какая конечная цель такой сложносочинённой схемы? Может можно попроще?

Comment: Да ботнет она собирает, с XSS. Помогите ей уже.

    header('Location: http://example.com/page1'); // работает?

Можно ещё добавить антикэш заголовков побольше.

Comment: В общем, Google Chrome почему-то не даёт программно уйти с первой страницы на вторую и затем сразу же со второй вернуться на первую. Ни с помощью заголовков, ни с помощью мета-тегов, ни с помощью javascript. Так вроде бы понятнее объяснила. :)

Comment: не понятнее, просто what you already tried ? просто код поможет гораздо лучше

Comment: а при чем тут js ? в вашем случае берите реферер если хочется.

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, хром всегда такой своеобразный. Попробуйте добавить к location "?rand={random}"

Comment: Можно например вместо редиректа во втором скрипте делать include("script1.php"); тогда он будет выполнен с уже установленными значениями.  
@istem, вряд ли это ботнет, скорее это сбор данных о браузере (физические размеры экрана, включены ли куки и яваскрипт)- в-общем те данные о клиенте, которые могут быть собраны при помощи яваскрипт.

Comment: Не смог воспроизвести проблему кстати говоря. Два скрипта:  
**test1.php**  

    <?
    if ($_COOKIE['test']!=3) header("Location: script2.php");
    echo "Script1<BR/>".$_COOKIE['test'];
    ?>

**script2.php**  

    <?
    setcookie("test", 3);
    header("Location: test1.php");
    ?>
    script2

В URL ввожу  

    http://localhost/test1.php

и вижу:  

    Script1
    3

То есть нормально прошел редирект в самом последнем хроме.

Comment: session_start() не забыли сделать ?

Comment: @eicto, переделал на такой вариант: проблема так же не воспроизводится.  
**test1.php** 

    <?
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['test']!=4) header("Location: script2.php");
    echo "Script1<BR/>".$_SESSION['test'];
    ?>

**script2.php**  

    <?
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['test']=4;
    header("Location: test1.php");
    ?>
    script2

Результат:  

    Script1
    4

Comment: я это у ТС спросил. :) конечно должно работать.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте Ajax для этого: сделайте логику запроса нужных скриптов на клиенте и проблема отпадет сама собой, т.к. редирект будет не нужен. Использовать редиректы "туда-обратно" - антипаттерн, который явно фильтруется браузерами.